# How to manipulate child's render output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I'm using a component form a third party library and I want to manipulate the render output.

Let's say we have two components:

```
// third party component that I don't have access to its code
const ThirdPartyComponent = () => (
  <div>
    <span>
      ...
    </span>
  </div>
)


// My component using the third party component
const MyComponent = () => (
  <div className="wrapper">
    <ThirdPartyComponent />
  </div>
)
```

Normally the output will be:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <span>
       ...
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to manipulate the third party component such that my component renders this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>
    ...
  </span>
</div>
```

*Or in other words **unwrap the rendered content** from an unwanted `<div />` element.*

**1. I can't change the third party code**

**2. The child component doesn't forward `ref`**

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Can you view or fork the third party code?

Comment: I can, but I don't want to fork and maintain a forked repo for such a simple tweak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If:

- the third party component is a function component, and
- the third party component does not use refs (or if you're careful), and
- you don't mind losing the component boundary for `ThirdPartyComponent` (essentially `MyComponent` will "be" `ThirdPartyComponent`), and
- you solemnly swear you understand this might break in the future

you can call the component as if it was a function, then dig into the returned JSX object and get the first child, á la:

```
const ThirdPartyComponent = () => (
  <div style={{border: "1px solid orange"}}>
    <span>...</span>
  </div>
);

const MyComponent = () =>  {
  const thirdPartyDiv = ThirdPartyComponent();  // This is naughty!
  const span = thirdPartyDiv.props.children;  // The child is the span
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      {span}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Alternately, if all you're doing is re-wrap the component, you could modify `thirdPartyDiv.props.className` to suit your needs...

```
const MyComponent = () =>  {
  const thirdPartyDiv = ThirdPartyComponent();  // This is naughty!
  thirdPartyDiv.props.className = "wrapper";
  return thirdPartyDiv;
}
```

Comment: Interesting... I'll try it, thanks. and may I ask why do you think calling a component as a function is naughty? Doesn't the react do the same?

Comment: Not quite. Doing `<ThirdPartyComponent />` is doing `React.createElement(ThirdPartyComponent, {})` – it doesn't immediately call the component (that's the React reconciler's job).

Comment: This is some serious crazy React dark magic going on here. What if I try it out? Alas, I fear the powers I could awake - but not control. Klaatu barada nikto. Klaatu barada nikto!