# Add another handler for "SyntheticEvent"

Tags: reactjs

There's a 3rd-party library that creates table rows and buttons inside those rows. Both `<tr>` and `<button>` are constructed with an "onClick" property, but the authors forgot to call `stopPropagation()` and so when clicking a button it also triggers the `<tr>` handler:

```
        render: (_text: any, record: TableRecord) => {
            return createElement(
                "button",
                {
                    className: button.actionButtonClass,
                    onClick: () => {
                        onClickHandler(
                            record,
                            button.actionButtonOnClickAction,
                            button.actionButtonOnClickMf,
                            button.actionButtonOnClickNf,
                            button.actionButtonOnClickForm,
                            button.actionButtonOnClickOpenPageAs
                        );
                    }
```

I can't alter the code above, but I tried to add another handler:

```
mxtreetable.componentDidUpdate = function() {
    mxtreetabledom.querySelectorAll(".actionButton").forEach((btn) => {
        if (!btn._my_have_stopPropagation) {
            btn._my_have_stopPropagation = true;
            btn.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
                ev.stopPropagation();
            });    
        }
    });
};
```

However, I learned that `PointerEvent` is not handled directly. It first bubbles to the container, then in the container's click handler it's wrapped with `SyntheticEvent` and that SyntheticEvent is passed back to the button. So calling `stopPropagation()` on the native event will prevent what we defined in the "onClick" property.

How do I subscribe to SynteticEvent so I can call stopPropagation on that event?

**Upd** This is what I came up with. It's full of hacks

```
// https://github.com/mendixlabs/mendix-tree-table/issues/35 BEGIN
function installOnClickHook(props) {
    if (!props.onClick._my_have_stopPropagation) {
        var oldOnClick = props.onClick;
        props.onClick = function(ev) {
            oldOnClick.apply(this, arguments);
            ev.stopPropagation();
        };
        props.onClick._my_have_stopPropagation = true;
    }
}

mxtreetable.componentDidUpdate = function() {
    mxtreetabledom.querySelectorAll(".actionButton").forEach((btn) => {
        var props = FindReactProps(btn);
        installOnClickHook(props);
    });
};

function FindReactProps(dom) {
    const key = Object.keys(dom).find(key=>{
        return key.startsWith("__reactProps$")
    });

    // Somebody assigns another __reactProps to <button> without componentDidUpdate() on parent component
    dom._my_props = dom[key];
    Object.defineProperty(dom, key, {configurable: true, get: function() {
        return this._my_props;
    }, set: function (x) {
      this._my_props = x;
      installOnClickHook(x);
    } });
  
    return dom[key];
}
// https://github.com/mendixlabs/mendix-tree-table/issues/35 END
```

Comment: Is the 3rd-party library opensource? Could you monkey-patch it? Does it offer any official way to inject a callback into the click handling? How do you use the lib? Does it return a `<tr>` as component root? If nothing else works there is one way to do it... but it is dark and not for the faint of heart: [calling render and modifying the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66965548/how-to-manipulate-childs-render-output)

Comment: @MArtin opensource? no;  monkey-patch? yes, but it's minified; official way to inject? no; <tr> as component root? I think the Field Set enclosing the table is the root because only a few widgets are React-based;